# How to make a partial match with an inflexible set of characters?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a simple regex that will take a specific set of characters and compare it to two separate options in the same line. I want it to choose the option that matches most closely, and if they match equally or not at all then take the first option.

Unfortunately, nothing can be optioned with the string characters that need matching because in the system I'm using (Keyboard Maestro, which uses ICU Regular Expressions) variables (`%Variable%`) can be incorporated in regular expressions. Variables are changing sets of characters, so each time the regex is used the set of characters will be definite but different from the last time. That being said, I think anyone can help me by just assuming the character set can't have anything done to it in the regex.

The two options are always separated by the literal | (`\|`) so it's easy to write that part of the regex.

Here are some examples of what I'm looking for:

`%Variable%` equals `abc`

In the string `xx xxaxx xx | xx xxbcxx xx` it would match the entire second string `xx xxbcxx xx` because it contained two consecutive matching characters while the first string only contained one.

Or in the string `xx xabcx xx | ab ababab ac` it would match the entire first string `xx xabcx xx` because it included three consecutive matching characters instead of just two like the second option.

Or in the string `xxabc | abcyy` it would match the first string `xxabc` because both strings matched equally so it takes the first.

Or in the string `poiu | lkjh` it would match the first string `poiu` because both strings matched equally (i.e. not at all) so it takes the first.

The %Variable% will often be a set of characters with no spaces but sometimes may have spaces, and it's of variable length, usually between 10 and 30 characters.

I really have no idea how to do this exactly. Googling and searching this site for "partial matches" and similar are showing me answers that won't work for this.

I've tried a lot of regexes, including `.*?(%Variable%*?).*?(\|)|(\|).*?(%Variable%*?).*?` and `.*?(%Variable%)*?.*?(\|)|(\|).*?(%Variable%)*?.*?`. That one was attempting to make the amount of characters in the %Variable% variable. I understand why it didn't work; I just can't think of how to make it work.

Comment: Do you have access to a grep tool?

Comment: No, I haven't worked with any grep tools before.

Comment: This is something you can't solve with regex alone, because this is not how a regular language would work.

Comment: I just thought of something like this: `(?:.*?(?=.*%Variable.*?{10})(/|)|.*?(?=.*%Variable.*?{9})(/|)|.*?(?=.*%Variable.*?{8})(/|) | (?:.*?(/|)(?=.*%Variable.*?{10})|.*?(/|)(?=.*%Variable.*?{9})|.*?(/|)(?=.*%Variable.*?{8})` and so on down to 0. It would only be a half-answer to my question since I think it would only match from the first of the %Variable% and not in-between %Variable characters (so the first example in my questions would match the first string instead). I'm guessing it won't work for some reason but I'm going to play around with it and keep an eye for any more replies here.